# how to install setup using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run install exe using batch script

```
set var =abc.exe
%var%
```

my script is like shown above if I write in script just abc.exe it is installing but if I assign path to variable and try to run than exe is not installing

```
set var = abc.exe
abc.exe
```

abc.exe is in current directory 
if batch script only having abc.exe than it is installing 
why if i assign exe path to var than not installing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between the variable and the executable name.

```
set var=abc.exe
```